# What is the entire time complexity of this recursive function with nested operations?

Tags: javascript, performance, recursion, time-complexity

I have the following top-down recursive function which calculates all of the different ways we can sum together numbers from `numbers` such that they equal `targetSum`. I am now trying to determine the time complexity of this problem exactly.

```
const allWays = (targetSum, numbers) => {

  const fn = (remainder, startIndex) => {
    if (remainder === 0) return [[]];

    const result = [];
    for (let i = startIndex; i < numbers.length; i += 1) {
      const num = numbers[i];
      if (remainder - num < 0) continue;

      const remainderWays = fn(remainder - num, i);
      const targetWays = remainderWays.map((way) => [num, ...way]);
      result.push(...targetWays);
    }

    return result;
  };

  return fn(targetSum, 0);
};
```

If we let the `m` be the size of `targetSum` and we let `n` be the length of `numbers`, then the recursion tree should have a height of `m` and a branching factor of `n` giving it a time complexity of `O(n^m)`.

While I understand that this exponential factor will dominate all other time complexities, I would still like to know what the `.map`, and two spread operators add to the runtime.

I cant seem to wrap my head around what the time complexity of this

```
const targetWays = remainderWays.map((way) => [num, ...way]);
result.push(...targetWays);
```

should be.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Both of those lines are iterations, together, something like O(n).  It is unintuitive that these shouldn't impact the time complexity, but I think that's because it's intuitive -- but wrong -- to equate complexity with run time.

Answer (score 0):

For both #map and #push, the time complexity would be `O(o)` since #map will iterate through the list/array and push will add inidividual element at the end of the list by iterating over `targetWays`. So both would be `O(o)` operation. (Considering `o` is length of result size)